# -contains VS -in

Tags: powershell, operators

Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7) has some duplicate containment operators, `-contains` vs `-in` & `-notContains` vs `-notIn`. The description makes it sound like these are basically identical, `-contains` is described as "Returns true when reference value contained in a collection" while `-in` is described as "Returns true when test value contained in a collection". What exactly is the difference between "reference value" and "test value" in this context?

And, are the options available all the way back to PS 2.0, or did `-in` & `-notIn` get introduced later? Given the many changes, I really wish MS would include this info in their documentation, rather than just assuming everyone is on the current version. But I digress. :)

Comment: All of the operators determine if a single item exists in a collection of items. The difference is which side of the operator that those items reside. With -contains, the left hand side (LHS) is the collection. With -in, the LHS is the single item.

Comment: @adminofthings, ah, so basically just an improvement in readability. Something that could also be improved in the documentation it seems. :) Thanks for the clarification! I tried testing this on an old Win7/PS2.0 VM, and got errors, so it seems that -in & -notIn got added later as well. Also good to know.

Comment: The typical scenario is a variable holds some value(s) and an expression is used to create the comparison value(s). The variable is typically on the LHS. I think that is probably just convention/readability.

Comment: If you run, `Get-Help About_Comparison_Operators`, you can see what is available in your current version. The `-in` and `-notin` variants were added in PowerShell v3. You can see that here [About_Comparison_Operators (v3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-3.0).

Comment: @adminofthings Interesting. When I searched I didn't get that link, I got one with MUCH less useful information. Bookmarked the good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for ease of use, since PowerShell is designed to be as comfortable to type (and read) in the shell as possible.

For `-contains` the collection is on the **left**-hand side:

```
(1, 2) -contains 1
```

The opposite case is the `-in` operator where the collection is on the **right**-hand side:

```
1 -in (1, 2)
```

This for is the very same reason why the negated versions exist too, simply because this:

```
1 -notin (1, 2)
```

is easier to type than this:

```
-not (1 -in (1, 2))
```